# JSoup Refreshing Page

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup, refresh

I got a problem with JSoup.
I wanted to make a little project where I read out data from a Radio Webpage. I want to read the current playing song and the artistname. (The page is: http://www.radiopilatus.ch/) right now it works more or less. My only problem is, sometimes when the song changes I don't always get the new data.. Is there a way to tell Jsoup to reload the page or something so I get the new data?

My code:

```
private void getData(){
    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.radiopilatus.ch/").get();

        //Artist
        Elements ereignisse = doc.select("#content > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.tile.livecenter > div > div.last-played > div > div.col-sm-8.title > span.artist");

        for(Element e : ereignisse){
            currSongArtist = e.text();
        }

        //Titel
        ereignisse = doc.select("#content > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.tile.livecenter > div > div.last-played > div > div.col-sm-8.title > span.song");

        for(Element e : ereignisse){
            currSongTitle = e.text();
        }
        doc = null;
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you take a look at [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), you'll notice that it's a statless protocol. That is, there's no out of the box feature to automatically refresh a page when it has been updated. Ergo, you need to do that yourself, either by loading the page periodically (I think something like every 10 sec would be acceptable). Or, more elegantly, if you're able to determine the remaining time of the current track, you can infer when the next track will play, thus producing the minimal amount of requests.

Comment: I'll try it with a bigger update-time. I don't think i can determine the remaining time of the current playing track, cause i only read out the HTML and in the HTML there is no info about the track length.
Thx For the help :)

Comment: Why a bigger interval? Worst case is that the song title gets updated 10 seconds after it started playing, which is not that insignificant, let alone times of 20 sec or bigger. Anyway, have a look at this url: [http://player.radiopilatus.ch/data/generated_content/pilatus/production/playlist/playlist_radiopilatus.json](http://player.radiopilatus.ch/data/generated_content/pilatus/production/playlist/playlist_radiopilatus.json). JSON is easier to parse and produces considerably less traffic. This will enable you to decrease the interval.

Comment: Which Library would you recommend me to parse JSON? Because I read that JSoup isn't made to parse JSON

Comment: [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Comment: Nice thx. I recoded it.. Gonna try it later. I can't try it now because i get a 403 error at work :(

Comment: Great. If you have a solution, please post it here as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recoded the thing and used JSON-Simple to parse a JSON file instead of a HTML file.

My updated Code:

```
  private void getData() {
try {
  String url = "http://player.radiopilatus.ch/data/generated_content/pilatus/production/playlist/playlist_radiopilatus.json";
  String jsonURL = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));
  //FileReader reader = new FileReader(jsonURL);
  JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
  JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(jsonURL);

  JSONArray playing = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("live");
  Iterator i = playing.iterator();

  while (i.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject)i.next();
    currSongTitle = (String)innerObj.get("title");
    currSongArtist = (String)innerObj.get("interpret");
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println(e);
  }
}
```

Thx to MCL for the help :)

Comment: Well done. But why are you looping over `data.live` and simply overwrite artist and title? More reasonable would be one of these two approaches: 1) You assume that only one song is being played at one point in time, and generally extract the first (and only) entry: `title = playing.get(0).get("title")` (I didn't care about type casting here). 2) You want to leave the door open for the possibility of multiple entries, in which case you want to store all of them, e.g. in an `ArrayList`, or even just reuse the `playing` object itself.

Comment: One last question: How did you get this path to the JSON-File?

Comment: Network analysis. In this case, I used HttpFox with FireFox. Chrome has a built-in tab in the developer console, which I find unhandy. For Windows, there's also Fiddler. The process is basically always the same: Navigate to the site/source and look at what resources have been loaded. JSON/XML and often also JS files frequently act as containers for interesting payload. Btw: I still don't like that loop in your code ;)